# FA icon in Bootstrap input: catch hover event with CSS

Tags: css, html, input, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

In `<input type="search">`, in webkit browser, you can see "X" icon which resets input value. Bootstrap 3, as I read, for some reasons do not support it. So I try to do this on my own, with Bootstrap 3 and Font Awesome 4.2.0, HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <label for="search" class="control-label col-xs-4">Search table</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control input-sm">
           <span class="fa fa-times form-control-feedback"></span>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

And here is CSS:

```
<style>
    .fa{
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    .form-control+.fa-times{
        color: red;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }

    .form-control:focus+.fa-times{
        color: blue;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .form-control:focus+.fa-times:hover{
        color: green;
        opacity: 1.0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

</style>
```

And it should work like this: normally, reset icon it red. When input has focus, icod should be blue - and it works. But last step, when input has focus and cursor is over icon which should be green - does not work. Next step is of course to create Javascript to reset input when user clicks con - but at first I need to catch hover event with CSS.
I would be happy if anybody decides to help me - thank you in advance.
Here is **code snippet**, which illustrates in 100% my problem:

```html
<!-- Font Awesome icons should be placed above Bootstrap to prevent bad has-feedback element
        alignment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/4313 -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<style>
        .fa{
            font-size: 1.3em;
        }

        .form-control+.fa-times{
            color: red;
            opacity: 0.4;
        }

        .form-control:focus+.fa-times{
            color: blue;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .form-control:focus+.fa-times:hover{
            color: green;
            opacity: 1.0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
<form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control input-sm">
                        <span class="fa fa-times form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: you might consider adding a `<input type="reset">` element, and styling that to look like the X instead of the span element. here is an example in which i've done exactly that on a different project: http://codepen.io/wbar8417/pen/oGgIB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is an interaction with bootstrap. The `form-control-feedback` class was designed for feedback to the user (like a checkmark or warning sign), and not for input from the user, and has the `pointer-events` property set to `none`, which means that it is impossible to interact with that element using your mouse. You can override that by adding `pointer-events: auto;` to your `.form-control+.fa-times` selector ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/amz9dw29/)).

Beyond that, I'd like to make a suggestion. The effect you're trying to achieve (creating a button that will clear the form) is something that exists in the HTML spec without any extra code, using the "reset" input type -- it's a button, just like a submit button, which clears all inputs in the form and resets the defaults. You can style this button to look like what you have above fairly simply. Below is an example.

[jsFiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/aq6en3pm/)

```css
#search_clear {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0.4;
    outline: none; /* override browser to hide blue outline when clicking */
    pointer-events: auto; /* override bootstrap to allow hovering/clicking */
}

#search:focus + #search_clear {
    color: blue;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#search:focus + #search_clear:hover {
    color: green;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control input-sm">
            <!-- this value attribute is the character code for the fa-times character -->
            <input type="reset" id="search_clear" class="form-control-feedback" value="&#xf00d;">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Pneumokok glad to help. developer inspection tools are your friend. :) just out of curiosity, will you be using the `<input type="reset">`, or just fixing the `pointer-events` property?

Comment: `<input type="reset">`, it seems to be more understandable for me (especially in my case, where search input will be the only one in form and it does not affect anything) and I think is more suitable to thing I want to achieve.